# Error en reportes dinamicos en SQL Server con .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Hago este *post* porque tengo un incoveniente con un proyecto en el que estoy trabajando. Cabe destacar que no lo he hecho, pero estoy realizando unas correcciones sobre él. Me he encontrado con un error que no he podido resolver.

Resulta que hay un módulo en el que se realiza un cambio de contraseña. Este funciona bien en la base de datos y realiza el cambio para el usuario actual. Luego se invoca un método para activar el usuario en el *Módulo de Reportes* de *SQL Server*. El método que invoca es éste:

```java
protected void btncambiar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  try {
    string contranueva = txtconfirmar.Text;
    string contractual = txtactual.Text;

    NegocioConfiguracion clsconfiguracion = new NegocioConfiguracion();
    Boolean sw = clsconfiguracion.cambiarcontra(contranueva,contractual);
    string login = HttpContext.Current.Session["nombreUsuario"].ToString();
    String rol = Session["rolUsuario"].ToString();

    if (rol == "Administrador" || rol == "GERENTE" || rol == "DIRECTOR" || rol == "RESIDENTE" || rol == "INVITADO") {
      try {
        Observatorio.SSRSUsuarios.UsrManager SSRSManager = new Observatorio.SSRSUsuarios.UsrManager();
        SSRSManager.activarUsuario("374F6CD15A364C03982015FB958E31ED", login, contranueva, login);
      } catch (Exception E) {
        using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("/Logs/") + "log.txt", true)) {
            tw.WriteLine("Error Cambiarcontraseña - btncambiar_Click " + E.Message + " " + DateTime.Now);
        }

        MostrarMensaje("La contraseña fue cambiada correctamente, pero fallo el modulo de reportes.");
      }
    }

    if (sw) {
      MostrarMensaje("Su Contraseña ha sido modificada exitosamente");
    }else { 
      MostrarMensaje("La Contraseña actual que ha proporcionado no es válida"); 
    }

  }catch (Exception E) {
    MostrarMensaje(E.Message);
  }
}
```

Lo que hace este método es recoger los parámetros de la clave anterior y la clave nueva e identificar el rol del usuario. Luego, invoca un método de cambio de clave desde el módulo `SSRSManager` que hace una referencia Web. El caso es que, luego entra en el método de activar usuario:

```java
public bool activarUsuario(string token, string usuario, string clave, string nombre) {
  object[] results = this.Invoke("activarUsuario", new object[] {
    token,
    usuario,
    clave,
    nombre
  });

  return ((bool)(results[0]));
}
```

Recibe el token, el login, la clave anterior y la nueva clave. Ya en este punto el código falla y devuelve la siguiente salida:

[image: Imagen_Error_Capture]

El proyecto lo subí al servidor de pruebas para probarlo directamente en un ISS, pero igual falla. No sé si alguien ya ha trabajado con este tipo de proyectos con *Reportes Dinámicos* en *SQL Server*. No sé si tenga que revisar alguna conexión en el servidor o alguna configuración.

NOTA:
Revisando el código me di cuenta que el protocolo que usa para realizar la invocación al soap es http://Tempuri.org/activarUsuario y según me informaron que tempuri.org ya esta obsoleto, tendrá algo que ver?

Comment: El problema puede estar en las propiedades de la conexión (porque se movió de una ubicación a otra) o en la configuración de la instancia que debe de tener habilitadas las conexiones remotas.

Comment: Tal como dice Luis, no es un problema de código, el problema es de la cadena de conexión (apunta a un servidor equivocado), a que los datos de conexión de la aplicación son incorrectos (user, password) o bien que el servidor no tiene habilitadas las conexiones remotas.

Answer (score 0):

El problema no es de código, sino de cortafuegos o permisos, tienes que permitir las conexiones al servidor local 127.0.0.0:80, eso se hace mediante ISP

Comment: Revisando el código me di cuenta que el protocolo que usa para realizar la invocación al soap es Tempuri.org y según me informaron que ya esta obsoleto, tendrá algo que ver?